# custom name dowloaded csv from the datatable package R

Tags: r, csv, dt

I have a problem in changing the name of csv downloaded, using the extension buttons of the datatable package, I want custom name of de csv, I'm trying to use the option JS for writing JavaScript code, but I'm not successful

```
library(DT)
datatable(head(iris, 30), 
          extensions = 'Buttons',

          options = list(
                  dom = 'Bfrtip',
                  buttons = list(list(extend = 'collection', buttons = c('csv','pdf'),text = 'Descarga'))
          ),
          callback = JS("
                        {
    extend: csv,
    text:   Save Log Info,
    filename: download1}
                        "))
```

Answer (score 6):

The configuration shld be in the options directly:

```
DT::datatable(
  mtcars,
  options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip', 
    buttons = list(
      list(
        extend = 'csv', 
        text = "Save Log Info", 
        title = 'download1'
      ), 
      'pdf'
    )
  ),
  extensions = 'Buttons',
)
```